# re.finditer erroring with “Expected string or bytes-like object”

Tags: python, regex, nltk, python-re

I have read multiple posts regarding this error. All I think is that I should use the python string function but I still can't figure it out.

the regex remove all the punctuation and keep the comma and dot between the word or number
for example 19,000 U.S

```
token_regex = re.compile("\w+([\,\.]\w+)*")
```

```
            text = text.lower()
            text_list = []
            #print(text)

            # Use token_regex
            # for loop for iteration
            #finditeraion
            for match in re.finditer(token_regex, text):
                text = match.start()
                text = match.end()
                text = match.group()
                tk_rx_text = text.replace('_','')
                # tk_rx_text = tk_rx_text.split()
                text_list.append(tk_rx_text)


            word_token = word_tokenize(text_list)
            print(word_token)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/calvinng/Documents/GitHub/CS172test/parsing.py", line 86, in <module>
    word_token = word_tokenize(text_list)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 130, in word_tokenize
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 108, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1274, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1328, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1328, in <listcomp>
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1318, in span_tokenize
    for sl in slices:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1359, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 316, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1332, in _slices_from_text
    for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I tried this but it shows the same error:

```
re.finditer(token_regex, str(text))
```

data type:
text = string, tk_rx_text = string, text_list = list

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind in these situations, does `re.finditer(token_regex, str(text))` work?

Comment: Seems that "text" is neither string nor bytes-like, so we need to check the type and the value of "text". maybe it is None?

Comment: @WiktorStribizew I tried that but it shows the same error.

Comment: @sagmansercan it's a string